# Java: Generic return type (illegal?) assignment conversion not causing compiler error

Tags: java, android

The following code:

```
public class test {
  private interface X {}

  private static <T extends X> T getX() {
    return (T)new X() {};
  }

  public static void main() {
    Float x = getX();
  }
}
```

Does not cause a compiler error in the `main()` method. This seems odd since `getX()` returns something which should extend X. Float does not extend X. There are types for which this is satisfied, for example `class Foo extends Float implements X`, but then you can assign the result of getX() to anything.

How do you make the compiler complain? Specifically if this is in library code (like Android's getParcelable which returns )?

Comment: [Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: `How do you make the compiler complain` - good question.

Comment: What do you think `new X() {};` is? Hint, `X` is an interface. If you guessed an anonymous class that implements `X` you're right.